MapBox : How to prevent events of the top layer trigger bottom layers?
I have mapbox with 3 layers:

Roof ( Polygon)
Panels ( Rectangle )
PanelsID ( circle )

When I hover or click on the PanelID layer (circle) which should remove all the panels, it triggers also the panel ( rectangle ) that's under the PanelID layer.
Screenshot

Code
"use client"

import { getRoofSurfaces } from "@/app/actions/roof-surfaces"
import { getEnv } from "@/env"
import * as turf from "@turf/turf"
import { Feature, GeoJsonProperties, Geometry, Position } from "geojson"
import mapboxGL, { Map as MapBoxMap } from "mapbox-gl"
import proj4 from "proj4"
import React, { SyntheticEvent, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"

import { Input } from "../ui/input"

/* eslint-disable */

interface Panel {
  panelID: number
  selected: boolean
}

interface Roof {
  id: number
  coords: any
  holes: any
  panelCoords: any
}

interface SelectedPanelsState {
  [roofId: number]: Panel[]
}

const FROM_PROJECTION = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" // Define the source and destination projections

const TO_PROJECTION = "EPSG:4326" // WGS84 Geographic

// Please check the backend response to understand how this function works

function convertCoordinates(wkt: any) {
  // Remove the POLYGON prefix and the outer parentheses, then split into rings
  const rings = wkt
    .replace(/POLYGON\s*\(\(/, "")
    .replace(/\)\)/, "")
    .split("), (")

  // Convert the rings into arrays of coordinates
  const convertedRings = rings.map((ring: string) => {
    // Map each ring to its coordinates
    let coordinates = ring.split(",").map((pair) => {
      let points = pair.trim().split(" ")
      return proj4(FROM_PROJECTION, TO_PROJECTION).forward([parseFloat(points[0]), parseFloat(points[1])])
    })

    // Ensure the ring is closed
    if (
      coordinates.length > 1 &&
      (coordinates[0][0] !== coordinates[coordinates.length - 1][0] ||
        coordinates[0][1] !== coordinates[coordinates.length - 1][1])
    ) {
      coordinates.push(coordinates[0])
    }

    return coordinates
  })

  // Structure the result as an object with 'outer' which is the roof and 'inners' which are the holes

  return {
    outer: convertedRings[0], // The first array is the outer boundary : Ex: Roof
    inners: convertedRings.slice(1), // All subsequent arrays are inner boundaries : Ex: Holes
  }
}

const BuildingMap = () => {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("")

  const [selectedPanels, setSelectedPanels] = useState<SelectedPanelsState>({})

  const mapRef = useRef<MapBoxMap | null>(null)

  const panelEventHandlers = useRef<{ [key: string]: any }>({})

  const roofEventHandlers = useRef<{ [key: string]: any }>({})

  const initMap = (token: string) => {
    if (mapRef.current) return

    mapRef.current = new mapboxGL.Map({
      accessToken: token,
      container: "map-container",
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9",
      zoom: 20,
      center: [6.934471401630646, 50.96733244414443],
      antialias: true,
      pitch: 20,
      attributionControl: true,
    })
  }

  const resetMap = () => {
    if (!mapRef.current) return

    // Remove all event handlers for panels and roofs
    Object.keys(panelEventHandlers.current).forEach((panelId) => {
      const { click, mouseenter, mouseleave } = panelEventHandlers.current[panelId]
      mapRef.current?.off("click", panelId, click)
      mapRef.current?.off("mouseenter", panelId, mouseenter)
      mapRef.current?.off("mouseleave", panelId, mouseleave)
    })
    panelEventHandlers.current = {}

    Object.keys(roofEventHandlers.current).forEach((roofSourceId) => {
      const { mouseenter, mouseleave, click, mouseenterCursor, mouseleaveCursor, roofCircleId } =
        roofEventHandlers.current[roofSourceId]
      mapRef.current?.off("mouseenter", roofSourceId, mouseenter)
      mapRef.current?.off("mouseleave", roofSourceId, mouseleave)
      mapRef.current?.off("click", roofCircleId, click)
      mapRef.current?.off("mouseenter", roofSourceId, mouseenterCursor)
      mapRef.current?.off("mouseleave", roofSourceId, mouseleaveCursor)
    })
    roofEventHandlers.current = {}

    // Remove all sources and layers starting with 'roof' or 'panels'
    const sources = mapRef.current.getStyle().sources
    const layers = mapRef.current.getStyle().layers

    layers.forEach((layer) => {
      if (layer.id.startsWith("roof") || layer.id.startsWith("panels")) {
        mapRef.current?.removeLayer(layer.id)
      }
    })

    for (const sourceId in sources) {
      if (sourceId.startsWith("roof") || sourceId.startsWith("panels")) {
        mapRef.current.removeSource(sourceId)
      }
    }
  }

  const fetchCoordinates = async (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/address-search/coordinates/?address=${address}`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ address }),
      })

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch coordinates")
      }

      const data = await response.json()

      const [lng, lat] = data.features[0].center

      mapRef?.current?.flyTo({
        center: [lng, lat],
      })

      // Reset the map layout
      resetMap()

      setSelectedPanels({})

      getRoofSurfaces(address)
        .then((roofSurfaces: any) => {
          installPvSystem(roofSurfaces)
        })
        .catch((error: unknown) => {
          if (error instanceof Error) {
            console.error("Error fetching coordinates:", error)
          }
        })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching coordinates:", error)
    }
  }

  const installPvSystem = (roofSurfaces: any) => {
    roofSurfaces.forEach((surface: any) => {
      surface.id = surface.roofId
      surface.coords = convertCoordinates(surface.roofGeometryWGS84).outer
      surface.holes = convertCoordinates(surface.roofGeometryWGS84).inners
      surface.panelCoords = surface.panelGeometriesWGS84.map((panelCoord: any) => convertCoordinates(panelCoord).outer)
    })

    roofSurfaces.forEach((roof: Roof) => {
      addRoof(roof)
    })
  }

  // Ensure that the toggleAllPanels function updates the paint properties as well
  function toggleAllPanels(roof: Roof, selectStatus: boolean) {
    mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(
      `roof-circle-${address}-${roof.id}`,
      "circle-color",
      selectStatus ? "#1d4ed8" : "transparent"
    )

    mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(
      `roof-${address}-${roof.id}`,
      "fill-color",
      selectStatus ? "#8fe03f" : "transparent"
    )

    mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(
      `roof-border-${address}-${roof.id}`,
      "line-color",
      selectStatus ? "#a3e635" : "#f8fafc"
    )

    mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(
      `roof-border-${address}-${roof.id}`,
      "line-dasharray",
      selectStatus ? null : [2, 2]
    )

    mapRef.current?.setLayoutProperty(
      `roof-text-${address}-${roof.id}`,
      "text-field",
      selectStatus ? `${roof.id}` : "+"
    )

    mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(`roof-${address}-${roof.id}`, "fill-opacity", selectStatus ? 0.4 : 0)

    // Update properties for each panel
    if (roof?.panelCoords) {
      roof.panelCoords.forEach((_: any, index: number) => {
        const panelId = `panels-${address}-${roof.id}-${index}`
        const panelIdLine = `${panelId}-line`

        mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelId, "fill-color", selectStatus ? "#020617" : "transparent")
        mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelIdLine, "line-width", selectStatus ? 0.2 : 0)
        mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelIdLine, "line-opacity", selectStatus ? 0.5 : 0)

        // Ensure hover and click events are managed correctly
        if (!selectStatus) {
          // Remove hover and click effects
          if (panelEventHandlers.current[panelId]) {
            const { click, mouseenter, mouseleave } = panelEventHandlers.current[panelId]
            mapRef.current?.off("click", panelId, click)
            mapRef.current?.off("mouseenter", panelId, mouseenter)
            mapRef.current?.off("mouseleave", panelId, mouseleave)
          }
        } else {
          // Reattach hover and click handlers if selecting
          const mouseEnterHandler = () => {
            if (mapRef.current) {
              const currentColor = mapRef.current?.getPaintProperty(panelId, "fill-color")
              if (currentColor !== "transparent") {
                mapRef.current.getCanvas().style.cursor = "pointer"
                mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelId, "fill-color", "#1e40af")
              }
            }
          }

          const mouseLeaveHandler = () => {
            if (mapRef.current) {
              const currentColor = mapRef.current?.getPaintProperty(panelId, "fill-color")
              if (currentColor !== "transparent") {
                mapRef.current.getCanvas().style.cursor = ""
                mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelId, "fill-color", "#020617")
              }
            }
          }

          const clickHandler = () => togglePanel(panelId, roof, index)

          panelEventHandlers.current[panelId] = {
            click: clickHandler,
            mouseenter: mouseEnterHandler,
            mouseleave: mouseLeaveHandler,
          }

          mapRef.current?.on("click", panelId, clickHandler)
          mapRef.current?.on("mouseenter", panelId, mouseEnterHandler)
          mapRef.current?.on("mouseleave", panelId, mouseLeaveHandler)
        }
      })
    }

    // Update selected panels state
    setSelectedPanels((prevSelectedPanels) => {
      const updatedRoofPanels = roof.panelCoords.map((_: any, index: number) => ({
        panelID: index,
        selected: selectStatus,
      }))

      return { ...prevSelectedPanels, [roof.id]: updatedRoofPanels }
    })
  }

  const addRoof = (roof: Roof) => {
    if (!mapRef.current) return

    const roofPolygonData = createRoofPolygonData(roof)
    const roofSourceId = `roof-${address}-${roof.id}`

    addRoofSource(roofSourceId, roofPolygonData)
    addRoofLayers(roofSourceId, roof)
    addRoofEventHandlers(roofSourceId, roof)
    const center = turf.center(turf.center(roofPolygonData))
    addCenterSourceAndLayer(roof.id, center)
    addPanelLayers(roof, roofPolygonData)
  }

  const createRoofPolygonData = (roof: Roof): Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties> => {
    const polygon = turf.polygon([roof.coords])
    const roofCoordinates = polygon.geometry.coordinates

    roof.holes.forEach((hole: Position[]) => {
      roofCoordinates.push(hole)
    })

    return {
      type: "Feature",
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: roofCoordinates,
      },
    }
  }

  const addRoofSource = (roofSourceId: string, roofPolygonData: Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>) => {
    if (mapRef.current?.getSource(roofSourceId)) {
      const source = mapRef.current.getSource(roofSourceId) as mapboxGL.GeoJSONSource
      source.setData(roofPolygonData)
    } else {
      mapRef.current?.addSource(roofSourceId, {
        type: "geojson",
        data: roofPolygonData,
      })
    }
  }

  const addRoofLayers = (roofSourceId: string, roof: Roof) => {
    if (!mapRef.current?.getLayer(roofSourceId)) {
      mapRef.current?.addLayer({
        id: roofSourceId,
        type: "fill",
        source: roofSourceId,
        paint: {
          "fill-color": "#8fe03f",
          "fill-opacity": 0.5,
        },
      })
    }

    const roofBorderId = `roof-border-${address}-${roof.id}`
    if (!mapRef.current?.getLayer(roofBorderId)) {
      mapRef.current?.addLayer({
        id: roofBorderId,
        type: "line",
        source: roofSourceId,
        layout: {},
        paint: {
          "line-color": "#a3e635",
          "line-width": 2,
        },
      })
    }
  }

  const addRoofEventHandlers = (roofSourceId: string, roof: Roof) => {
    const handleMouseEnter = () => handleRoofMouseEnter(roofSourceId, roof)
    const handleMouseLeave = () => handleRoofMouseLeave(roofSourceId, roof)
    const handleClick = () => handleRoofClick(roofSourceId, roof)

    const handleMouseEnterCursor = () => {
      if (mapRef.current) {
        mapRef.current.getCanvas().style.cursor = "pointer"
      }
    }
    const handleMouseLeaveCursor = () => {
      if (mapRef.current) {
        mapRef.current.getCanvas().style.cursor = ""
      }
    }

    const roofCircleId = `roof-circle-${address}-${roof.id}`

    // Store event handlers for cleanup

    roofEventHandlers.current[roofSourceId] = {
      mouseenter: handleMouseEnter,
      mouseleave: handleMouseLeave,
      click: handleClick,
      mouseenterCursor: handleMouseEnterCursor,
      mouseleaveCursor: handleMouseLeaveCursor,
      roofCircleId,
    }

    mapRef.current?.on("mouseenter", roofSourceId, handleMouseEnter)
    mapRef.current?.on("mouseleave", roofSourceId, handleMouseLeave)
    mapRef.current?.on("click", roofCircleId, handleClick)
  }

  const handleRoofMouseEnter = (roofSourceId: string, roof: Roof) => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      if (mapRef.current.getPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-color") === "transparent") {
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-color", "#f8fafc")
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-opacity", 0.1)
        return
      }

      if (mapRef.current.getPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-color") !== "transparent") {
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-color", "#500724")
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(`roof-border-${address}-${roof.id}`, "line-color", "#f8fafc")
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-opacity", 0)
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(`roof-circle-${address}-${roof.id}`, "circle-color", "transparent")
        mapRef.current.setLayoutProperty(`roof-text-${address}-${roof.id}`, "text-field", "X")
      }
    }
  }

  const handleRoofMouseLeave = (roofSourceId: string, roof: Roof) => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      if (mapRef.current.getPaintProperty(`roof-border-${address}-${roof.id}`, "line-dasharray")) {
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-color", "transparent")
        return
      }

      if (mapRef.current.getPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-color") !== "transparent") {
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-color", "#8fe03f")
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(`roof-border-${address}-${roof.id}`, "line-color", "#a3e635")
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-opacity", 0.4)
        mapRef.current.setPaintProperty(`roof-circle-${address}-${roof.id}`, "circle-color", "#1e3a8a")
        mapRef.current.setLayoutProperty(`roof-text-${address}-${roof.id}`, "text-field", `${roof.id}`)
      }
    }
  }

  const handleRoofClick = (roofSourceId: string, roof: Roof) => {
    if (mapRef.current) {
      const currentColor = mapRef.current.getPaintProperty(roofSourceId, "fill-color")
      if (currentColor !== "#f8fafc" && currentColor !== "transparent") {
        toggleAllPanels(roof, false)
      } else {
        toggleAllPanels(roof, true)
      }
      // Stop event propagation to ensure it doesn't affect underlying layers
      mapRef.current.getCanvas().style.cursor = ""
    }
  }

  const addPanelLayers = (roof: Roof, roofPolygonData: Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>) => {
    if (roof.panelCoords) {
      roof.panelCoords.forEach((panelCoords: any, index: number) => {
        addPanel(roof, panelCoords, index)
      })

      setSelectedPanels((prevSelectedPanels: SelectedPanelsState) => {
        const updatedRoofPanels = roof.panelCoords.map((_: any, index: number) => ({
          panelID: index,
          selected: true,
        }))

        return { ...prevSelectedPanels, [roof.id]: updatedRoofPanels }
      })
    }
  }

  const addCenterSourceAndLayer = (roofId: number, center: Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>) => {
    const centerSourceId = `roof-circle-${address}-${roofId}`

    mapRef.current?.addSource(centerSourceId, {
      type: "geojson",
      data: center,
    })

    if (!mapRef.current?.getLayer(centerSourceId)) {
      mapRef.current?.addLayer({
        id: centerSourceId,
        type: "circle",
        source: centerSourceId,
        paint: {
          "circle-radius": 30,
          "circle-color": "#1e3a8a",
          "circle-stroke-width": 4,
          "circle-stroke-color": "white",
        },
      })
    }

    const textLayerId = `roof-text-${address}-${roofId}`

    mapRef.current?.addLayer({
      id: textLayerId,
      type: "symbol",
      source: centerSourceId,
      layout: {
        "text-field": `${roofId}`,
        "text-size": 20,
      },
      paint: {
        "text-color": "white",
      },
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedPanels)
  }, [selectedPanels])

  const togglePanel = (panelId: string, roof: Roof, index: number) => {
    setSelectedPanels((prevSelectedPanels) => {
      const updatedRoof = [...prevSelectedPanels[roof.id]]
      updatedRoof[index] = { ...updatedRoof[index], selected: !updatedRoof[index].selected }

      const allUnselected = updatedRoof.every((panel) => !panel.selected)

      // Update the paint properties based on the new selected state
      const newColor = updatedRoof[index].selected ? "#1e40af" : "transparent"
      const panelLineId = `${panelId}-line`

      mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelId, "fill-color", newColor)
      mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelLineId, "line-width", updatedRoof[index].selected ? 1 : 2)
      mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelLineId, "line-color", updatedRoof[index].selected ? "white" : "#020617")
      mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelLineId, "line-opacity", updatedRoof[index].selected ? 0.5 : 1)
      mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelLineId, "line-dasharray", updatedRoof[index].selected ? null : [2, 2])

      if (allUnselected) {
        toggleAllPanels(roof, false)
      }

      return { ...prevSelectedPanels, [roof.id]: updatedRoof }
    })
  }

  const addPanel = (roof: Roof, panelCoords: any, index: number) => {
    const panelFeature: Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties> = {
      type: "Feature",
      properties: { panelId: index },
      geometry: { type: "Polygon", coordinates: [panelCoords] },
    }

    const panelId = `panels-${address}-${roof.id}-${index}`

    const panelLineId = `${panelId}-line`

    mapRef.current?.addSource(panelId, {
      type: "geojson",
      data: panelFeature,
    })

    // Check if the panel layer exists
    mapRef.current?.addLayer(
      {
        id: panelId,
        type: "fill",
        source: panelId,
        paint: {
          "fill-color": "#020617",
          "fill-opacity": 1,
        },
      },
      `roof-circle-${address}-${roof.id}`
    )

    mapRef.current?.addLayer(
      {
        id: panelLineId,
        type: "line",
        source: panelId,
        paint: {
          "line-color": "white",
          "line-opacity": 0.5,
        },
      },
      `roof-circle-${address}-${roof.id}`
    )

    const clickHandler = () => togglePanel(panelId, roof, index)

    const mouseEnterHandler = () => {
      if (mapRef.current) {
        mapRef.current.getCanvas().style.cursor = "pointer"
        const currentColor = mapRef.current?.getPaintProperty(panelId, "fill-color")
        if (currentColor !== "transparent") {
          mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelId, "fill-color", "#1e40af")
        }
      }
    }
    const mouseLeaveHandler = () => {
      if (mapRef.current) {
        mapRef.current.getCanvas().style.cursor = ""
        const currentColor = mapRef.current?.getPaintProperty(panelId, "fill-color")
        if (currentColor !== "transparent") {
          mapRef.current?.setPaintProperty(panelId, "fill-color", "#020617")
        }
      }
    }

    // Store event handlers for cleanup

    panelEventHandlers.current[panelId] = {
      click: clickHandler,
      mouseenter: mouseEnterHandler,
      mouseleave: mouseLeaveHandler,
    }

    mapRef.current?.on("click", panelId, clickHandler)
    mapRef.current?.on("mouseenter", panelId, mouseEnterHandler)
    mapRef.current?.on("mouseleave", panelId, mouseLeaveHandler)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getEnv().then((env) => {
      const token = env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOCKER_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN!
      initMap(token)
    })
    return () => mapRef?.current?.remove()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='h-screen flex flex-col items-stretch'>
      <form onSubmit={fetchCoordinates}>
        <Input
          className='my-2 w-1/3 mx-auto'
          placeholder='Enter address'
          value={address}
          onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
      <div id='map-container' className='flex-1'></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BuildingMap



The mapboxGL.Map component has an interactiveLayerIds property that controls the active layers on which onClick or onHover events can be triggered.
You will need to assign an array of active layer IDs to the interactiveLayerIds property to make it work on specific layers. Please refer to the section of onClick event from react-map-gl documentation.
